# Delete lines which match with words in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with different words which correspond with my patterns

WORDS.TXT

```
842
897
907
967
995
1065
1095
```

And other file containing the lines that I want to remove when match with the word.txt

```
816.42743   9246.4688
832.41711   8867.3076
842.51001   23988.459
859.42639   5776.8726
870.53418   5992.9668
875.41742   6930.3584 
877.43384   35639.199 
885.51709   60137.957
891.41595   5480.983
```

Therefore, the new fille should remove line 3 bacause it matches with a word of the pattern, `842`.

The final file should be:

```
816.42743   9246.4688
832.41711   8867.3076
859.42639   5776.8726
870.53418   5992.9668
875.41742   6930.3584 
877.43384   35639.199 
885.51709   60137.957
891.41595   5480.983
```

I also need the pattern of the words (word.txt) recognizes only the numbers before the point.
Thanks, I hope to be clear

Answer (score 3):

Using a way [recommended into GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Other-Arguments) to parse the files:

```bsh
awk -F '.' 'pass == 1 {seen[$0]}
            pass == 2 && !($1 in seen)' pass=1 words.txt pass=2 file
```

At first pass, we save every line (`$0`) of `words.txt` as a key of the associative array `seen`.

At second pass, we print only lines form `file` where the first field (`$1`) does not exist into `seen`.

`-F '.'` sets the field separator (`FS`) to the literal dot.

Output:

```
816.42743   9246.4688
832.41711   8867.3076
859.42639   5776.8726
870.53418   5992.9668
875.41742   6930.3584 
877.43384   35639.199 
885.51709   60137.957
891.41595   5480.983
```

Comment: That's a suggested way to read the same file twice, not to read 2 different files.

Comment: Indeed. I don't find any reason for not expanding to 2 different files.

Comment: It's fine, it's just not `the recommended way ... to parse two files`. It's not necessary as there are other ways to do the same thing with existing constructs in all awks (e.g. NR==FNR or FILENAME==ARGV[1], etc.) and GNU awk additionally has ARGIND, it's just when you have to process the same file twice that an incremental variable between appearances of that file becomes more useful.

Comment: ok, I rephrased that. Of course I use `FNR==NR` or anything like `FNR==1` for many files to identify the change of input file, because they are convenient. Probably for the limits of the input space, e.g. an empty file, using a variabe or `ARGV` is safier. It's good to have documented many ways of doing thngs.

Comment: I do too, but be aware that Stéphane Chazela recently noted correctly that the `FNR==NR` approach fails if the first file turns out to be empty.

Comment: @AdminBee that's well known and it's not the only approach (see `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` or `ARGIND` as I mentioned), all I'm saying is that setting a variable between files like this is the arguably preferred solution to a different problem than just having 2 input files..

Comment: @EdMorton I did not mean to disagree with your statement, only caution against a possibly unreflected use of `FNR==NR` (considering it is the approach seen most often here to distinguish the first file from the following files - including in my answers).

Comment: Understood completely, there's just a couple of well known things you don't need to explain every time you write common, idiomatic awk code and `NR==FNR` is up there with `1` :-).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'.' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} !($1 in a)' words.txt file2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep, but you need another tool to enforce the "before the point" requirement

```
grep -v -w -f <(sed 's/^/^/' words.txt) file2
```

- grep can take a file containing patterns: `-f`
- but we want to transform the file of numbers to regular expressions, so the process substitution with sed
- you want to match whole words: `-w`
- and you want to invert the matching: `-v`